# Нет доступа к хранилищу

Tags: android, unity3d, android-permissions

Я декомпилировал apk файл моего проекта чтобы просмотреть его android manifest. В манифесте есть такие строчки:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Первая строчка это для получения разрешения на использование камеры, и при запуске приложения у меня появляется окно которое спрашивает разрешить ли использовать камеру. Однако не появляется запроса на использование внутренней памяти. Я посмотрел в настройках телефона, разрешения которые есть у данной программы. Там есть разрешения: Камера и Память.

[image: Скрин разрешений]
 Флажок у камеры находится в активном состоянии, однако память находится в неактивном, хотя как видно выше у меня есть `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` и  `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` то есть хотя бы запрос должен появится.Но его нету. Кто сталкивался с таким, как решили проблему? И да я для примера добавлял флаг `android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES` и тогда оно у меня запрашивало доступ к изображениям и файлам на устройстве. И после флажок был активен.

Comment: Запрос надо самому делать.  Плюс реакция на флажок "не спрашивать больше"

Comment: @Игорь самому, то есть вручную через настройки? Или что вы имеете ввиду?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Народ нашел решение. Так как эта тема еще будет актуальна, то вот мое решение проблемы. Не знаю почему, но когда в настройках unity стоит Write Permission: Internal то оно как то коряво работает с внутренней памятью. То есть запрос на использование внутренней памяти не появляется. После этого я сделал простой скрипт на создание папки. Папка и вложенные в нее не создались. После этого я по новому собрал приложение но, с Write Permission: external(sdcard). После этого я установил приложение, и запрос при запуске на использование памяти появился. После этого моему скрипту удалось создать папку на внимание! внутреннем хранилище. То есть как пишется в доках unity external(sdcard) эта опция позволяет работать с sdcard если есть, а если нет то будет с внутренней памятью. Вот мой тестовый скрипт:

```
public void BtnClick()
{
    string paths = "/storage/emulated/0/";
        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(paths);
        dir.CreateSubdirectory("Folder/Videos");
    dir.CreateSubdirectory("Folder/Images");

}
```

Протестировано на устройствах: Xiaomi Redmi note 6 pro и samsung galaxy s7 edge. Возможно это многие знают, но почему то когда я искал как использовать внутреннее хранилище, я натыкался на статьи, где надо было "Танцевать с бубном". 
Такой путь: /storage/emulated/0/ работает вполне безотказно. И не нужно никаких функций для получения внутреннего хранилища.